# Why is the MIME type application/octet-stream not called byte-stream?

Tags: mime-types, naming

As far as I understand an octet and byte are similar if not the same thing. So why is the MIME Type called octet-stream and not byte-stream?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Bytes can be octets, and mostly are, but they are not synonyms. A byte is generally considered an octet, but it doesn't need to be one.

The mime type uses the word "octet" because it's a stream of 8-bit values: the total size of the data in bits streamed when the stream correctly ended is a multiple of 8. A byte isn't required to be 8 bits, it depends on the machine, architecture and some other things (FFFFFFFFE out of FFFFFFFFF times a byte is an octet though).

---

Remember: octets **are** 8 bits, bytes **can be** 8 bits.

Comment: Put differently, the definition of "byte" is platform dependent; the definition of "octet" is not.